# using underscore _reduce to convert an array to object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can i convert this array

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b','c', 'd']
```

to an Object

```
object = { a:2 , b:2, c:2, d:2 }
```

using only javascript underscore _reduce ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, can you please post your attempt?

Comment: [_.countBy](https://underscorejs.org/#countBy) and please check the docs before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.reduce((obj, currentKey) => {
  if(currentKey in obj) {
     obj[currentKey] = obk[currentKey] +1
  } else{ 
    obj[currentKey] = 1
  }

return obj;
}, {});
```

and testd on your code, here is the output

[image]

Comment: FYI - When you're posting an answer, the 7th button from the left (with an icon similar to `<>`) in the editor will allow you to create a working js snippet that will show the output of the code :)

Comment: thanks @AlonEitan , im kinda new so now very familiar to these stuff

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b','c', 'd'];

var obj = [...new Set(array)]
    .reduce((acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [cur]: array.filter(item => item === cur).length
    }),
{});

console.log(obj);
```